# How to hide default footer and display custom footer?

Tags: lotus, websphere-portal, wcm, lotus-wcm

I created a custom theme , I want to hide the default footer for page created with this theme , but when I comment out the code to display footer in theme.html , then it hides footer for all the pages of portal.

What configuration should I do to hide default footer and display custom footer on my pages  and display the default footer on rest of the portal pages.

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pranav,

where exactly are you commenting?
Portal theme by default will be linking to portal 8 footer.jsp. u need to chenge it to your custom theme footer.jsp. then u ll not see the default footer.jsp and it ll always use ur custom theme footer.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Update the footer.jsp under dynamicspots of your custom theme.